# RibbonSplitButton click event

Tags: wpf, ribbon

Gentelman,

I'm binding a collection to RibbonSplitButton (basically, showing 3 values: red, green, blue) Everything works fine except of the problem I have to figure out which color (item) has been chosen:

Here's my code:

```
<r:RibbonSplitButton Name="TagEm" 
    LargeImageSource="Images\pencil_32.png"
    Label="Tag"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TagCollection}"
    Click="TagEm_Click">
    <r:RibbonSplitButton.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Descr}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </r:RibbonSplitButton.ItemTemplate>
</r:RibbonSplitButton>
```

Code behind:

```
private void TagEm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Something like `(Tag)TagEm.Items.CurrentItem`;

Could someone give me a hint, please?

Many thanks in advance!

N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use the RibbonSplitButton Click event. Instead use the TextBox MouseLeftButtonUp event.

XAML:

```
<r:RibbonSplitButton
    Name="TagEm"
    LargeImageSource="Images\pencil_32.png"     
    Label="Tag"     
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TagCollection}">
    <r:RibbonSplitButton.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" MouseLeftButtonUp="TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonUp" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </r:RibbonSplitButton.ItemTemplate>
</r:RibbonSplitButton>
```

Event Handler:

```
private void TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Tag clickedTag = (sender as TextBlock).DataContext as Tag;
}
```

Comment: Of course, that only works for Mouse input. If you want to support keyboard or other inputs, replace the TextBlock with a Button (and handle Button.Click). You can make the Button look like a TextBlock using Control Templates http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230084.aspx